# CF7 custom dropdown [select] function does not display values

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have been working on this function for several days and I cannot seem to get the results to display in the dropdown menu I created in contact form 7.  I could use some help.

The form has the following shortcode

```
 [select* city_dropdown]
```

The code is able to create a $tag array that is passed to the CF7 [select].  My understanding is that the 'raw_values' or 'values' fields of this array should be displayed in the dropdown menu.

```
Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Array ( ) [values] => Array ( ) [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => 
[0] => Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Burnaby,BC [values] => Burnaby,BC [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Kelowna,BC [values] => Kelowna,BC [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Calgary,AB [values] => Calgary,AB [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => ) 
[3] => Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Calgary,AB [values] => Calgary,AB [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => ) 
[4] => Array ( [type] => select* [basetype] => select [raw_name] => city_dropdown [name] => city_dropdown [options] => Array ( ) [raw_values] => Burnaby,BC [values] => Burnaby,BC [pipes] => WPCF7_Pipes Object ( [pipes:WPCF7_Pipes:private] => Array ( ) ) [labels] => Array ( ) [attr] => [content] => ) )
```

However, the list of cities that is in the raw_values and values fields are not being displayed in the dropdown menu.  Am I putting the value in the right spot?
Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'filter_wpcf7_form_tag_select_city_list', 10, 2);

function filter_wpcf7_form_tag_select_city_list($tag, $unused) {
if ( $tag['name'] != 'city_dropdown') {
       return $tag;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes($tag['raw_values']);
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'pi_counter';
    $count_query = "select count(*) from $table_name";
    $num = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);
    $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
    $arg = $tag;
    if($retrieve_data) {
         foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data) {
              $seats= $retrieved_data->Count_value;
              if($seats != '0'){
                        $arg['raw_values'] = $retrieved_data->City;
                        $arg['values'] = $retrieved_data->City;
                        $arg['pipes'] = $pipes;
                          array_push($tag, $arg);
              }
         }
     }
     else {
          echo 'no results or error<br>';
          echo 'error: ' . $wpdb->print_error();
     }
//      $tag = array_unique($tag,$tag['values']);
  //      echo '</br></br>';
//        print_r($tag);
        return $tag;
}
```

Bug #1

The list of cities is supposed to appear in the drop-down select field.  Here is a link to the result I see now.  The drop-down field is under the label "Event Location'

https://bk.pinterec.ca/2021/11/25/wereg/

**Any idea why the list of cities is not displayed?**

It is supposed to look like this:
Burnaby,BC
Kelowna,BC
Calgary,AB
Calgary,AB
Burnaby,BC

Bug #2

There is a nagging bug in the code....for some reason, the code runs twice.  when I do a print_r($tag) I see the array displayed twice.   Minor issue but if you see why...please point it out.

**Why does the function run twice?**

Bug # 3

For some reason, the array_unique is not filtering out the duplicates.

$tag = array_unique($tag,$tag['values']);   // Fourth line from the bottom

**Any idea why?**

Comment: sorry bug #3 is supposed to be  $tag = array_unique($tag);   But this line makes the website crash.

Comment: An easier way to achieve custom select fields is to use the [Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) extension's `[dynamic_dropdown]` tag which allows you to build lists using either posts/taxonomies or even a hooked filter.  There is a handy [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&list=PLblJwjs_dFBsynXEstrV3fCIC7GBmK9HW&index=5) on how to use it too.  So you can maintain your list in a taxonomy, and it will dynamically update the select field.

Comment: interaction with my database is the most important.  I need to be able to get data from the database, show it as a list, display a value, change the value and update the database.  The field layout is easy to do with HTML.

Comment: taxonomy are designed for maintain lists (hierarchical or not) and much easier to do so than in an HTML script.